# toggle value in json java

Tags: java, json, toggle

How can I toggle the boolean value each time and then assign it to "`test`" key in my json?

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
json.put("test",true);
return json.toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to get the current value, flip it, and set it back.

```
String jsonText = "{\"test\":true}"; // or wherever you have your json
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
if (json.has("test")) {
    json.put("test", !json.getBoolean("test"));
} else {
    json.put("test", true);
}
```